# Transform text menu to HTML links in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm transforming a text only menu / command structure into HTML links in JavaScript.  The text spans that I receive are of the form:

```
<span>1. First option           2. Second option       </span>
<span>3. Third option                                  </span>
```

I'd like a link for each menu item, with the link text being 'First option', 'Second option', etc. The main problem is that the spans have white-space: pre on them, and I need to retain all the spaces within the span.  That is, the length of the text within each span cannot change.

I've been able to create the links with regular expressions using subpatterns and the replace method, but I can't seem to both not select the entire span, and also not have the white-space in the subpattern.  This is what I had that does get both links in the same span separated, but leaves in the spaces:  `/(\d*)\.\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*)/g`

Comment: You've got yourself a crappy problem. Why is this menu formatted as crappy html? It would a lot more sense to define it json or even xml.

Comment: Screen scraping an old command line system, dynamically putting to the web.  Pretty neat, but you do have to deal with crap like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to learn negative lookahead:) Here's what I got:

> /((\d+).\s)((?:[^\d\s]|\s(?!(?:\s*\d*.)|(?:\s*$))|\d(?!(?:\d*.\s)))*)/g

$1 contains the '1.  ', $2 contains the '1', $3 contains the menu text.  It works pretty good actually.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
var links='';
$('span').each(function(){
var text = this.innerText.replace(" ","");
var a= '<a href="#">' + text + '</a>';
links += a;
});

$('span').parent().html(links);
```

Comment: This does not work in a variety of ways, including that it loses white space, and does not create separate links for each menu command. It also wipes out all the spans, which is a bad side effect.